# What are *.inc files in LLVM build

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am working with a debug build of llvm and writing a pass. It takes about 5-10 minutes to build every time I run 'make'. I see a lot of *.inc files getting build every time. What are those files and how can I make builds go faster?

Thanks

Comment: The `.inc` files are generated files that are included in C++. Each file is generated in its own way. You probably ought to investigate one of them to find out what it depends on and why it's being built. Choose one at random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably talking about files generated by TableGen utility. This process is slow for you because you've built it in Debug mode, probably. There is a CMake option called `LLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN` to build TableGen in Release mode regardless the build type of all other projects.